# Have to get the number of letters in an ArrayList of strings

Tags: java, arraylist

If I am given an ArrayList of strings, i.e. `{"hello", "goodbye", "morning", "night"}`, how do I check how many `a`'s, `b`'s, `c`'s, etc. there are in the list?

The method must return an array of `int`s, where position [0] is the numbers of `a`'s, etc. For example, the `returnArray[1] = 1`, because there is one `b` in the list. Is there a better way to do this than simply hardcoding each letter?

```
public static int[] getLetters( ArrayList<String> list) {
    int [] result = new int[25];
    if(list.contains('a')) {
        result[0] = result[0] + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a better way than repeating the above strategy 25 more times?

Comment: You need to get each character, you can then use the character to index the array

Comment: If I understand your question correct, it does not matter that "hello" and "goodbye" (etc.) are separate words. A string with a concatenation of all the elements in the list would lead to the same result. Is that true? What about uppercase and any non alphabet characters?

Comment: `new int[25]` is going to cause you all sorts of grief, unless you're Greek. Though, given you're using `a/b/c` instead of `α/β/γ`, that's unlikely.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `char` as a means to address the array, for example...

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"hello", "goodbye", "morning", "night"}));
int[] results = new int[26];
for (String value : list) {
    for (char c : value.toCharArray()) {
         // 'a' is the lowest range (0), but the ascii for 'a' is 97
        results[c - 'a'] += 1;
    }
}
```

Which results in...

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

*nb:* This will only work for lower case characters, if you have any upper case characters, you'll get an array out of bounds error.  You could put range checking in for each character to make sure it's between `a` and `z`, but that's up to you

Comment: Kudos for just using 26. Though,as stated, production-ready code should be bulletproof against a string like `"WTF?"` :-)

Comment: What about `results[c - 'a']++;`

Comment: @paxdiablo That would come down to the requirements, which are clearly defined (and you are right), in this case (as I understand it), I might 1. convert the `String` to lowercase to start with and then check to see if the `char` is between `a` and `z` and basically discard all the characters, but that assumes we only care about those characters ;)

Comment: I don't think that calling `toCharArray` for each input element is a good idea. This method copies internal char array. Iterating using indexed `for` loop and fetching characters with `charAt` will be more efficient.

Comment: @Aivean Possibly, but I'm lazy and it was easier to type

Comment: @MadProgrammer how would I go about the program if some are not lowercase? i.e. {"HeLLo", "GOOdBye"}

Comment: That depends, do you care?  Do you want to separate the lower case from the uppercase?  If not, you could just convert the characters to lower case and not care.  Otherwise, if you have a look at [a ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), you will see that `A` is lower then `a`, but there are also other characters between `Z` and `a`, so you'd need to provide some more offset calculations and allow for the differences between upper and lower case characters, something like `('a' - 7) - 'A'` for lower case characters `'A' - char` for upper case characters

Comment: It does not matter, I simply have to lower case all the chars to add them up, but I can't seem to find the right method in the Java API to do this. Also, is your program all I need to get the method getLetters work? I tried running it through my tester class but it gave errors

Comment: `String#toLowerCase` for the whole `String` or [`Character#toLowerCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase-char-) if you just want to do it to the character, either will do the same job essentially

Answer (score 0):

Yo can convert your Array toCharArray() and then you can compare each letter with the alphabet you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you give me a quick bit of code to show me how that would work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on a `map` and the `Character` class as follows:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String w1 = "samefoo";
        String w2 = "barsame";

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add(w1);
        al.add(w2);

        // this is your method --->
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for(String str: al) {
            for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
                char k = str.charAt(i);
                if(map.containsKey(k)) {
                    map.put(k, map.get(k) + 1);
                } else {
                    map.put(k, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        // <---

        for(char c: map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(c + ":" + map.get(c));
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, all the ones not in the map have implicitly 0 as counter.

Answer (score 0):

With java 8, you could do it this way:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("hello", "goodbye", "morning", "night"));

Map<String, Long> map = list.stream()
    .flatMap(word -> Arrays.stream(word.split("")))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        letter -> letter, 
        Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(map); // {r=1, b=1, t=1, d=1, e=2, g=3, h=2, i=2,
                         // y=1, l=2, m=1, n=3, o=4}
```

Building the required array from this map is left as an excercise to the reader ;)